# How to check the content of an edit text in developing android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i'm just a beginner in developing android apps.
i have this code in my .java file . All i wanted is that if either the EditText fields 1 or 2 is empty, then message pops using Toast, else the result.setText() will appear . However, when i'm trying to emulate this, and one or two of the EditText fields are empty the program crashes and stops. PLease help! Thank you !

```
  EditText height = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  EditText weight = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);   
  EditText result = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

  if(height.getText().toString()== "" || weight.getText().toString()==""){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error! Height or Weight is empty! ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
    result.setText("Accepted.");
}
```

Comment: Do `if(TextUtils.isEmpty(height.getText().toString()));`

Comment: Post the logs of the error

Comment: the syntax doesn't have an error, it's when i try to run the code in an emulator, and when either of them is empty it just say "UNfortunately, the program has stopped."

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText heightEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
height = heightEditText.getText().toString();
if (height.matches("") || TextUtils.isEmpty(height)) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error! Height or Weight is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

Comment: i tried this one but the same thing happened.. "unfortunately, the program has stopped."

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   if (height.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) 
    {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter height", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
    else if (weight.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {            
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter height", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
    result.setText("Accepted.");
}
```